# Custom Interactive Presentation Transition

Tags: ios, uikit, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationcustom

I am attempting to create a custom view controller container, which will display a drawer at the bottom of the screen, like the Apple mail or music apps, and I want the user to either be able to tap on it to transition it to fullscreen, or slide it up interactively to reveal the content.

[image]

I have the drawer working, using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to slide it.
I can implement this by adding the content controller as a child controller,  the content view to the hierarchy and call `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` when appropriate.

But I wish to allow the content view controller to animate alongside the swipe (e.g. any animations in `viewWillAppear:`, like with interactive pop), thus I am looking at custom modal presentation and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, but I am hitting a wall, and I can't see why this is happening. I have setup a transitioning delegate, returning a custom animation controllers and an interaction controller which is a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` object.

My drawer is part of the container controller's view hierarchy, and naturally I want the content controller's view to be a subview of the drawer. But when calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, a new `UITransitionView`subview is added to the `UIWindow`, supposedly for where the transition animation should occur. But this kills my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and the user cannot perform the swipe to open the drawer.

I tried creating a custom `UIPresentationController` and other ways to control where in the hierarchy this `containerView` should be, but I am unable to change the behavior.

Is what I am attempting to do the correct way? What have I missed?

---

If anyone is interested, here is my framework: [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController)

Comment: Here is good tutorial: http://imnotyourson.com/draggable-view-controller-interactive-view-controller/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2015.11.19

A demo project as well

**Obj-C** -> https://github.com/saiday/DraggableViewControllerDemo

**Swift 2.x** -> https://github.com/ostatnicky/DraggableViewController

**Swift 4.x** -> https://github.com/satishVekariya/DraggableViewController

Thanks [@avdyushin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364228/avdyushin) mentioned my blog post.

And yes, my post [Draggable view controller? Interactive view controller!](http://imnotyourson.com/draggable-view-controller-interactive-view-controller/) is a tutorial just about your topic.

Quoted from my blog post:

#### How to do it

Design philosophy

There is no two `UIViewController` in together, instead there's only one `UIViewController` at a time. When user begin drag on certain subview, present another view controller with custom [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/) by custom [UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition_class/).

Technical things

These two protocols is the foundation of customize interactive `UIViewController` transitions. In case you don't know yet, take a glance before starting.
1. [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/)
2. [UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition_class/)

Answer (score 5):

An updated answer for iOS 10: this is now trivial using [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator?language=objc).

`UIViewPropertyAnimator` is a continuation of the block-based animation concept, taken to its logical continuation - an object oriented wrapper around animations. This allows for much more control, such as controlling the completion of the animation using `fractionComplete` - precisely what was needed here.